# How to use left join of sql in Rethinkdb ReQL with secondary index?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have two table `A` and `B`I would like  to use `left join` in sql that means all content of A and only common content of B.
I tried to use outer join like:

```
r.table("A").outerJoin(r.table("B"),function(a,b){
      return a("id")==b("anotherfield")("joinfield")
})
```

but the Query is very slow as there is no index in table `B`. 
How can I use my secondary index when querying `outerjoin`?

Equivalent sql

```
select * from A
left join a.id = b.other_field_join
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `map` here:

`r.table('a').map(function(row) {
  return {left_row: row, right_rows: r.table('b').getAll(row('id'), {index:'idx'})};
})`

Comment: This method works with with single value like "count", but not others, errors `RqlRuntimeError: Expected type DATUM but found SELECTION:`

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time trying to use **concatMap** instead of **outerJoin** to speed up results

Example available here:

https://rethinkdb.com/docs/sql-to-reql/javascript/

But that's throw error:

```
Expected type DATUM but found SELECTION
```

That happen due to **do** operation it takes only basic data types not selection result

Solution that worked with me:

```
r.table("A")
.concatMap(function(rowA) {
    .getAll(rowA("other_field_join"), {index: 'other_field_join'})
    .coerceTo('array')
    .do(function (result) {
        return r.branch(
          result.count().eq(0)
        , [{left: tableA}],
          result.map(function (rowB) {
            return {
              left:rowA, right: rowB
            };
          })
        )
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter SELECTION to DATUM, change following

```
right_rows: r.table('b').getAll(row('id').coerceTo('ARRAY')
```

But do you intend ONE TO MANY JOIN?

In case of ONE TO ONE JOIN, you can get result faster just by adding secondary index.

```
r.table("B").indexCreate("anotherfield")

r.table("A").outerJoin(r.table("B"), function(left, right) {
  return left("id").eq(right("anotherfield"));
})
```